# What's the origin of foo and bar?

Tags: terminology, history, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using “Foo” and “Bar” in examples](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/using-foo-and-bar-in-examples)

I know AT&T labs used them in their Unix days, but do they have even deeper histories?

Comment: Here in italy, instead of foo and bar, we have Pippo (Goofy).. Awful! Ex: var pippo = 'ciao'.

Comment: @Philip Ngan: I've suggested that in the Wiki, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108/should-the-point-distribution-system-be-changed-to-encourage-discussion-not-answ/192#192 It didn't have much attention yet though, maybe we should create a new question with that text.

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [Jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html):

> When ‘foo’ is used in connection with ‘bar’ it has generally traced to the WWII-era Army slang acronym FUBAR (‘Fucked Up Beyond All Repair’ or ‘Fucked Up Beyond All Recognition’), later modified to foobar. Early versions of the Jargon File interpreted this change as a post-war bowdlerization, but it it now seems more likely that FUBAR was itself a derivative of ‘foo’ perhaps influenced by German furchtbar (terrible) — ‘foobar’ may actually have been the original form.
>
> For, it seems, the word ‘foo’ itself had an immediate prewar history in comic strips and cartoons. The earliest documented uses were in the Smokey Stover comic strip published from about 1930 to about 1952. Bill Holman, the author of the strip, filled it with odd jokes and personal contrivances, including other nonsense phrases such as “Notary Sojac” and “1506 nix nix”. The word “foo” frequently appeared on license plates of cars, in nonsense sayings in the background of some frames (such as “He who foos last foos best” or “Many smoke but foo men chew”), and Holman had Smokey say “Where there's foo, there's fire”.

Answer (score 24):

tl;dr

- "Foo" and "bar" as metasyntactic variables were popularised by MIT and DEC, the first references are in work on LISP and PDP-1 and Project MAC from 1964 onwards.
- Many of these people were in MIT's Tech Model Railroad Club, where we find the first documented use of "foo" in tech circles in 1959 (and a variant in 1958).
- Both "foo" and "bar" (and even "baz") were well known in popular culture, especially from Smokey Stover and Pogo comics, which will have been read by many TMRC members.
- Also, it seems likely the military FUBAR contributed to their popularity.

---

The use of lone "foo" as a nonsense word is pretty well documented in popular culture in the early 20th century, as is the military FUBAR. (Some background reading:
[FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/metasyntactic+variables)
[FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/foo)
[Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html)
[Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html)
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)
[RFC3092](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3092.html))

---

OK, so let's find some references.

**STOP PRESS!** After posting this answer, I discovered this perfect article about "foo" in the Friday 14th January **1938** edition of [The Tech](http://tech.mit.edu/V57/PDF/N57.pdf) ("MIT's oldest and largest
newspaper & the first newspaper published on the web"), Volume LVII. No. 57, Price Three Cents:

> On Foo-ism
>
> The Lounger thinks that this business of Foo-ism has been carried too far by its misguided proponents, and does hereby and forthwith take his stand against its abuse.
> It may be that there's no foo like an old foo, and we're it, but anyway, a foo and his money are some party. (Voice from the bleachers- "Don't be foo-lish!")
>
> As an expletive, of course, "foo!" has a definite and probably irreplaceable position in our language, although we fear that the excessive use to which it is currently subjected may well result in its falling into an early (and, alas, a dark) oblivion. We say alas because proper use of the word may result in such happy incidents as the following.
>
> It was an 8.50 Thermodynamics lecture by Professor Slater in Room 6-120. The professor, having covered the front side of the blackboard, set the handle that operates the lift mechanism, turning meanwhile to the class to continue his discussion. The front board slowly, majestically, lifted itself, revealing the board behind it, and on that board, writ large, the symbols that spelled "FOO"!

[The Tech newspaper](http://tech.mit.edu/V57/PDF/N30.pdf), a year earlier, the Letter to the Editor, September **1937**:

> By the time  the  train  has  reached  the station  the  neophytes  are  so  filled with  the  stories  of  the  glory  of  Phi Omicron  Omicron,  usually  referred  to as  Foo,  that  they  are  easy  prey.
>
> ...
>
> It  is  not  that  I  mind  having  lost my  first  four  sons  to  the  Grand  and Universal  Brotherhood  of  Phi  Omicron  Omicron,  but  I  do  wish  that  my fifth  son,  my  baby,  should  at least  be warned  in  advance.
>
> Hopefully  yours,
>
> Indignant  Mother  of  Five.

And [The Tech](http://tech.mit.edu/V58/PDF/N48.pdf) in December **1938**:

> General  trend  of  thought  might  be best  interpreted  from  the  remarks
> made  at  the  end  of  the  ballots.  One vote  said,  '"I don't  think  what  I  do  is any  of  Pulver's  business,"  while another  merely  added  a  curt  "Foo."

---

The first documented "foo" in tech circles is probably **1959**'s [Dictionary of the TMRC Language](http://www.gricer.com/tmrc/dictionary1959.html):

> FOO:  the sacred syllable (FOO MANI PADME HUM); to be spoken only when under inspiration to commune with the Deity. Our first obligation is to keep the Foo Counters turning.

These are explained at [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/TMRC). The dictionary's compiler Pete Samson said in 2005:

> Use of this word at TMRC antedates my coming there. A foo counter could simply have randomly flashing lights, or could be a real counter with an obscure input.

And from 1996's [Jargon File 4.0.0](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/b/baz.html):

> Earlier versions of this lexicon derived 'baz' as a Stanford corruption of bar. However, Pete Samson (compiler of the TMRC lexicon) reports it was already current when he joined TMRC in 1958. He says "It came from "Pogo". Albert the Alligator, when vexed or outraged, would shout 'Bazz Fazz!' or 'Rowrbazzle!' The club layout was said to model the (mythical) New England counties of Rowrfolk and Bassex (Rowrbazzle mingled with (Norfolk/Suffolk/Middlesex/Essex)."

A year before the TMRC dictionary, **1958**'s MIT Voo Doo Gazette ("Humor suplement of the MIT Deans' office") [(PDF)](http://web.mit.edu/voodoo/www/archive/pdfs/1958-Jun.pdf) mentions Foocom, in "The Laws of Murphy and Finagle" by John Banzhaf (an electrical engineering student):

> Further research under a joint Foocom and Anarcom grant expanded the law to be all embracing and universally applicable: If anything can go wrong, it will!

Also **1964**'s MIT Voo Doo [(PDF)](http://web.mit.edu/voodoo/www/archive/pdfs/1964-Jan.pdf) references the TMRC usage:

> Yes! I want to be an instant success and snow customers. Send me a degree in:
> ...
>
> - Foo Counters
> - Foo Jung

---

Let's find "foo", "bar" and "foobar" published in code examples.

So, [Jargon File 4.4.7](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/foobar.html) says of "foobar":

> Probably originally propagated through DECsystem manuals by Digital Equipment Corporation (DEC) in 1960s and early 1970s; confirmed sightings there go back to 1972.

The first published reference I can find is from February **1964**, but written in June 1963, [The Programming Language LISP: its Operation and Applications](http://books.google.com/books?ei=ynbhTd2PK8nUsgbQurSABg&ct=result&id=eH0sAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22project%20mac%22%20%2bfoo&q=foo#search_anchor) by Information International, Inc., with many authors, but including Timothy P. Hart and Michael Levin:

> Thus, since "FOO" is a name for itself, "COMITRIN" will treat both "FOO" and "(FOO)" in exactly the same way.

Also includes other metasyntactic variables such as: FOO CROCK GLITCH / POOT TOOR / ON YOU / SNAP CRACKLE POP / X Y Z

I expect this is much the same as this next reference of "foo" from MIT's Project MAC in January **1964**'s AIM-064, or [LISP Exercises](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5924) by Timothy P. Hart and Michael Levin:

> car[((FOO . CROCK) . GLITCH)]

It shares many other metasyntactic variables like: CHI / BOSTON NEW YORK / SPINACH BUTTER STEAK / FOO CROCK GLITCH / POOT TOOP / TOOT TOOT / ISTHISATRIVIALEXCERCISE / PLOOP FLOT TOP / SNAP CRACKLE POP / ONE TWO THREE / PLANE SUB THRESHER

For both "foo" and "bar" together, the earliest reference I could find is from MIT's Project MAC in June **1966**'s AIM-098, or [PDP-6 LISP](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5899) by none other than Peter Samson:

> EXPLODE, like PRIN1, inserts slashes, so (EXPLODE (QUOTE FOO/ BAR)) PRIN1's as (F O O // /  B A R) or PRINC's as (F O O /   B A R).

---

Some more recallations.

[@Walter Mitty](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/using-foo-and-bar-in-examples/69803#69803) recalled on this site in 2008:

> I second the jargon file regarding Foo Bar. I can trace it back at least to 1963, and PDP-1 serial number 2, which was on the second floor of Building 26 at MIT. Foo and Foo Bar were used there, and after 1964 at the PDP-6 room at project MAC.

[John V. Everett](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/f2dcd4247b866a62/fc54f0f7d7329fb5) recalls in 1996:

> When I joined DEC in 1966, foobar was already being commonly used as a throw-away file name. I believe fubar became foobar because the PDP-6 supported six character names, although I always assumed the term migrated to DEC from MIT. There were many MIT types at DEC in those days, some of whom had worked with the 7090/7094 CTSS. Since the 709x was also a 36 bit machine, foobar may have been used as a common file name there.
>
> Foo and bar were also commonly used as file extensions. Since the text editors of the day operated on an input file and produced an output file, it was common to edit from a .foo file to a .bar file, and back again.
>
> It was also common to use foo to fill a buffer when editing with TECO. The text string to exactly fill one disk block was IFOO$HXA127GA$$. Almost all of the PDP-6/10 programmers I worked with used this same command string.

[Daniel P. B. Smith](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/6d8f44f725ef0e5d/0a6112662a880ddd) in 1998:

> Dick Gruen had a device in his dorm room, the usual assemblage of B-battery, resistors, capacitors, and NE-2 neon tubes, which he called a "foo counter."  This would have been circa 1964 or so.

[Robert Schuldenfrei](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/f2dcd4247b866a62/fc54f0f7d7329fb5) in 1996:

> The use of FOO and BAR as example variable names goes back at least to 1964 and the IBM 7070.  This too may be older, but that is where I first saw it.  This was in Assembler.  What would be the FORTRAN integer equivalent? IFOO and IBAR?

[Paul M. Wexelblat](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/39c4d97bdd57a5ee/8db07ccaf99fc014) in 1992:

> The earliest PDP-1 Assembler used two characters for symbols (18 bit machine) programmers always left a few words as patch space to fix problems. (Jump to patch space, do new code, jump back)  That space conventionally was named  FU: which stood for Fxxx Up, the place where you fixed Fxxx Ups.  When spoken, it was known as FU space. Later Assemblers ( e.g. MIDAS allowed three char tags so FU became FOO, and as ALL PDP-1 programmers will tell you that was FOO space.

[Bruce B. Reynolds](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/f2dcd4247b866a62/fc54f0f7d7329fb5) in 1996:

> On the IBM side of FOO(FU)BAR is the use of the BAR side as Base Address Register; in the middle 1970's CICS programmers had to worry out the various xxxBARs...I think one of those was FRACTBAR...

Here's a straight [IBM "BAR"](http://books.google.com/books?ei=bWfhTYeeNs7Osga10ciLBg&ct=result&id=mgUuAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22Base%20Address%20Register%22%20bar&q=bar#search_anchor) from 1955.

---

Other early references:

- [1967 foo bar MIT AIM-127](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5868)
- [1967 foo bar MIT AIM-127a](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/6136)
- [1965 foo MIT Tech Engineering News](http://books.google.com/books?ei=8WzhTfOPBo3ysgbBnvjsBQ&ct=result&id=aOQRAQAAMAAJ&dq=f00%20pdp&q=foo#search_anchor)
- [1968 foo baz DEC](http://books.google.com/books?ei=ZSzhTaPbGYuVswaMoPT9BQ&ct=result&id=80UsAQAAIAAJ&dq=foo%20baz&q=baz#search_anchor)
- [1971 FOO BAR UCLA-NMC RFC269](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc269)
- [1972 FOO MIT AI](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/41939)
- [1972 FOO MIT AI HAKMEM](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html) ([PDF scan](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6086/AIM-239.pdf?sequence=2))
- [1972 FOO DEC](http://books.google.com/books?ei=PSHhTdjDO8rLswbXr5WDBg&ct=result&id=jZdPAAAAYAAJ&dq=foo%20%20%22Digital%20Equipment%20Corporation%22&q=foo#search_anchor)
- [1973 FOO DEC](http://books.google.com/books?ei=viLhTbe8Cs_3sgaC48SPBg&ct=result&id=VfQRAQAAMAAJ&dq=%2bfoo%20%20%22Digital%20Equipment%20Corporation%22&q=foo#search_anchor)
- [1973 foo bar International Joint Council on Artificial Intelligence](http://books.google.com/books?id=glNQAAAAMAAJ&q=foo%20bar&dq=foo%20bar&hl=en&ei=7NTfTdnmNM2WOpKL7YIK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ)
- [1975 foo bar International Joint Council on Artificial Intelligence](http://books.google.com/books?id=qVRQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22foo%20bar%22&dq=%22foo%20bar%22&hl=en&ei=CdTfTe69LcqUOuSQ8fcJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA)
- [1977 Foobar](http://books.google.com/books?ei=19XfTcSeBMKBOvWTuegJ&ct=result&id=NpsZAQAAIAAJ&dq=%2bfoobar&q=foobar#search_anchor)
- [1978 Foobar](http://books.google.com/books?id=zqomAAAAMAAJ&q=foobar&dq=foobar&hl=en&ei=EdbfTYWNIJCSOozL6Y4K&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA)
- [1978 Moby Foobar in Software Wars](http://www.panda.com/tops-20/software-wars.html)

---

I haven't been able to find any references to foo bar as "inverted foo signal" as suggested in RFC3092 and elsewhere.

Here are a some of even earlier F00s but I think they're coincidences/false positives:

- [1959 "FOO 31 IBM-704 Bettis Plant Uses a least squares technique" U.S. Atomic Energy Commission](http://books.google.com/books?ei=W2rhTf_oIZCTswbVv8z7BQ&ct=result&id=mOkuAAAAIAAJ&dq=ibm%20foo&q=foo#search_anchor)
- [1960 FOO (FO Out, F1, F2, FOO, FOI) "Digital computer and control engineering"](http://books.google.com/books?ei=WyXhTfP9AYePswbtl6GQBg&ct=result&id=uo_QAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2bfoo%20signal%20-fog&q=foo#search_anchor)
- [1967 FOO?](http://books.google.com/books?ei=8iHhTY6SPMvJswbD1eWFBg&ct=result&id=aGVXAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2bfoo%20%20%22Digital%20Equipment%20Corporation%22&q=%20foo#search_anchor)

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar):

> The origins of the terms are not known with certainty, and several anecdotal theories have been advanced to identify them. Foobar may have derived from the military acronym FUBAR and gained popularity due to the fact that it is pronounced the same. In this meaning it also can derive from the German word furchtbar, which means awful and terrible and described the circumstances of the Second World War.
>
> FOO is an abbreviation of Forward Observation Officer, a British Army term in use as early as the First World War. The etymology of foo is explored in the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) Request for Comments 3092, which notes usage of foo in 1930s cartoons including The Daffy Doc (with Daffy Duck) and comic strips, especially Smokey Stover and Pogo. From there the term migrated into military slang, where it merged with FUBAR.
>
> "Bar" as the second term in the series may have developed in electronics, where a digital signal which is considered "on" with a negative or zero-voltage condition is identified with a horizontal bar over the signal label; the notation for an inverted signal foo would then be pronounced "foo bar".